# PHP5 what is the use case of type hiting in php

Tags: php, type-hinting

```
function(myCar $cars)
```

In PHP5, type hinting is a specifying class name before object variable in a function parameters.

I know what is type hinting, but what is the exact use case in PHP5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the examples in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php):

> Failing to satisfy the type hint results in a catchable fatal error.

It helps to detect errors or wrong usage of functions.